# Resque vs Sidekiq?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, resque, sidekiq

I am currently using `Resque` for my background process but recently I heard a lot of huff-buff about `sidekiq`. Could anybody compare/differentiate?

In particular I would like to know is there a way to monitor programmatically whether a job is completed in `sidekiq`

Comment: Ryan has created a webcast for Sidekiq this week which also include some comparison with Resque. You probably want to check it out: Url:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq

Comment: Am so psyched to see that this question has not been closed as being "not appropriate for SO".

Comment: Can we stop closing all the good question please people. I know it's quite broad, it's also quite important and quite interesting.

Comment: One day they will invent a site where programmers can ask questions, and that site will allow subjective responses. Questions that can be ignored, or even voted on based on relevance.

Comment: @baash05 and it will be called Quora!

Comment: It will be called Yahoo Answers, and the quality will plummet through the floor.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

#### Resque:

Pros:

- does not require thread safety (works with pretty much any gem out there);
- <s>has no interpreter preference (you can use any ruby);</s>
  [Resque currently supports MRI 2.3.0 or later](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/master/README.markdown)
- loads of plugins.

Cons

- runs a process per worker (uses more memory);
- does not retry jobs (out of the box, anyway).

#### Sidekiq:

Pros

- runs thread per worker (uses much less memory);
- less forking (works faster);
- more options out of the box.

Cons

- **[huge]** requires thread-safety of your code and **all dependencies**. If you run thread-unsafe code with threads, you're asking for trouble;
- works on some rubies better than others (jruby is recommended, efficiency on MRI is decreased due to GVL (global VM lock)).

Comment: How do you know if you're running "thread unsafe code"?

Comment: For example, if you're storing state in global variables, then you're in trouble :) As for the gems, here are some [in the wiki](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Problems-and-Troubleshooting).

Comment: If you're using MRI (official ruby) everything is always thread-safe, because of the GVL. So you are safe if you are using MRI (but performance may be worse depending on what you're doing).

Comment: @mrbrdo You can't be more wrong. GVL has nothing to do with thread-safety of your ruby code. GVL is about thread-safety of ruby interpreter code (MRI C code).

Comment: I have to contradict the 'pro' on Resque that says 'you can use any ruby'. The README for Resque today actually says 'We would love to support non-MRI Rubies, but they may have bugs.' https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/master/README.md#requirements

Comment: @JellicleCat can you do the edit? Strike-through that point and add comment about resque now being MRI-only (with link)

Comment: I would particularly avoid Sidekiq if you're planning to run JavaScript inside your jobs using therubyracer. Not a fault of Sidekiq per se but the multi-threading causes issues for therubyracer. See https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer/issues/206

Comment: Where's the reference link for "jruby and rubinius are recommended" for SideKiq?

Comment: @RyanBuckley: hm, weird. Rubinius used to be recommended. But now can't find a mention of it anymore in github repo.

Comment: being able to run multiple processes in Resque, makes it faster in multicore systems.

Comment: @vasilakisfil: does it offset the cost of forking? :shrug: This needs to be properly measured. Besides, you can simply run several sidekiq processes.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Ofcourse the longer the jobs the better. But usually a job split in 2+ processes that run parallely will always be faster than 1.

Answer (score 10):

From the question:

> In particular I would like to know is there a way to monitor
>   programmatically whether a job is completed in sidekiq

Here's a solution for that:

1. [Sidekiq::Status gem](https://github.com/utgarda/sidekiq-status)
2. Batch API (Sidekiq Pro) - [usage](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/536)