# Celery like software for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, distributed-computing

Is there anything similar to [Celery](http://celeryproject.org) for Ruby? Is there anyone with any experience with [rcelery](https://github.com/leapfrogonline/rcelery)? Is it a good choice for production?

Update: I came across [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque), which looks like something I might be able to use for my task. Any further suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a lot of options for queues in ruby.

Sidekiq -> https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq
Resque, you got the link
DelayedJob -> http://blog.leetsoft.com/delayed_job/

All of them are pretty much the same. So you just need to use the one you are more confortable working with the examples.
In my projects i ended up using `Sidekiq`, the reviews about it are pretty awesome.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a good comparison of Resque and Sidekiq.
[Resque vs Sidekiq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580954/resque-vs-sidekiq)

Sidekiq uses threads so there is a much lower memory footprint then Resque or delayed job.  the downside, and a huge one i think, is your workers MUST be thread safe, including whatever gems you use in them.  vetting all the code that goes into workers for thread safety is a on-taking for sure, as is potentially debugging contention in lower level libs, seg faults, etc..